# VB.net - print pdf file with printer with paper size

Tags: c#, vb.net, pdf, printing

I'm building an application which main function is printing .pdf files.
I searched a lot, and can't find the thing I need, so here is my question.

I would like to create a method that prints a .pdf file with a selected printer and paper size. ( we have a plotter that goes from A0 - A3 drawings ) so a great range off different sizes could be in the batch.

`Public Sub print_pdf(byval document as string, byval printer as string, byval size as string)`

I found this similar post, but.. it's written in `c#` and I can't read it.. I'm only familiar with vb.net.

[Link to post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097005/how-to-set-printer-settings-while-printing-pdf)

All our PC's are equipped with acrobat reader, but if there is a better method for printing? I'm open to suggestions!

Please help.. i'm stuck!!

---

I found also this sample code in `c#`

```
string path = "" <- your path here.
    if (path.EndsWith(".pdf"))
        {
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
                info.Verb = "print";
                info.FileName = path;
                info.CreateNoWindow = true;
                info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                Process p = new Process();
                p.StartInfo = info;
                p.Start();
                p.WaitForInputIdle();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
                if (false == p.CloseMainWindow())
                    p.Kill();
            }
        }
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457307/print-existing-pdf-file) post. Is there a way to idle untill the print queue is done? and then print a kill the process?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing an external PDF document in VB.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26970825/printing-an-external-pdf-document-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Default PDF reader such as Acrobat or FoxitReader , Open your File then Print it, it's simple.
This is C# code :

1. get the full path for your PDF File :

   ```
    String fullpath =System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@FilePath);
   ```
2. Open it using the Default PDF Reader :

   ```
   Process.Start(@fullpath);
   ```